# PHP Using Get Post in WHERE function

Tags: php, sql, web, where-clause

On one page I have a form which `POST`s the data entered in the 1 field across to another page.

On this page which you are directed to after entered data in the form field is a connection to a sql database. It happily re`POST`s the form field data on the page. Then I have got the PHP for retrieving the information from the database. This works nicely when the `WHERE` part is fixed manually ('criteria') however I would like the WHERE criteria for this search to be the form data from the previous page.

is there a way to echo the data to it? The form data is successfully getting to the displaying page however need help with the `WHERE` part.

That line of code currently is...

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 'formdata'");
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, query compares `field` to the actual string `'formdata'`. You'll want to grab the `formdata`, if you're POSTing, like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table 
                              WHERE field = '" . $_POST['formdata'] . "'");
```

Although, note that you'll need to use prepared statements to make this secure. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: You forgot to call `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or switch to a parametrized query.

Comment: Yeah, the code snippet I included is pretty barebones as is. I'd rather it be parameterized - I'll update to that soon. It was more a demonstration of where the `formdata` value comes from, and what to do with it, since OP stated he was new to using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I use PDO, but mysqli should be roughly the same

```
$formdata = $_POST['input'];
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $formdata);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```